# Python Beginner: Removing nan form an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

So im working with an array of arrays, i want to calculate the mean of each array inside this array, but some of the arrays have nan values.

I dont want to remove the whole array, just the nan obejct.

im using numpy, and the array is of type float64

I have tried some of the solutions on here, but with no luck.

```
values = np.split(dflow['fixf'].to_numpy(), np.where(np.diff([int(elem[3:]) for elem in dflow['ftid']]))[0] + 1) # creating the array of arrays

final = []
for index, value in enumerate(values):
    [[i for i in j if not np.isnan(x)] for j in values] # attempt to remove the nan values via iteration (did not work)
    final.append(value.mean()) # calculating the mean

analysis = pd.DataFrame({'value': final, 'hour': np.concatenate([[x for x in range(24)] for y in range(7)]),
                         'day': np.concatenate([np.full(24, index) for index in range(7)])}) # the mean should end up in the list final.
```

Below is the example array for **values**

```
values [array([11.26034969, 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 ]), array([2.19253936, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([nan, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306])
```

i have included a sample of the arrray of arrays

Comment: Welcome to SO ! did you consider using np.nanmean as documented here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html ?  Best

Comment: thanks! yes i did try it, but it still passes through - thats why i considered doing ilteration

Comment: @KristianBonderup - The line after for loop has no assignment, why is it being done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a quick one. There might be better solution out there.

```
# this was the array of arrays  you posted
# I have used np.nan to produce nan values
# and np.array to build the each array element again 
myarray = np.array([ np.array([np.nan, 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 , 12.9716698 ]), np.array([2.19253936, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649, 2.83246649]), np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), np.array([np.nan, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306, -0.73396306])])

# now you could get a mask of values that are not nan in your array
noNanValues= [~np.isnan(i) for i in myarray  ]

# use the mask to remove nan values from your array and save as list
newArray =  [j[noNanValues[i]] for i,j in enumerate(myarray)] 
# if you want back an array 
newArray2 =  np.array([newArray])


# check the first array to ensure the Nan has been removed
newArray[0].shape
newArray2[0][0].shape

# compute mean and other desired operation
```

You could also consider importing your arrays into a data frame and dealing with  Nan conveniently  there.